# How can I put the sign of OR (`||`) into a while loop?

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, while-loop, integer

In C++, why can I not put the sign of OR (`||`) in a while loop like this?

```
int weight_of_Limak,weight_of_Bob,sum=0;
cin>>weight_of_Limak>>weight_of_Bob;

while((weight_of_Limak<weight_of_Bob) || (weight_of_Limak!=weight_of_Bob))
{
    sum++;
    weight_of_Limak*=3;
    weight_of_Bob*=2;

}
cout<<sum;
```

Comment: That should be fine. What error are you getting? How is it not working? Note that the first part of your condition is moot. If it's true, then you know for sure the second is also true already.

Comment: What problem are you having? The code is syntactically okay. You don’t need all those parentheses, and the first test isn’t needed, because if it’s true the second one will be, too.

Comment: Have you tried running this code? Does it not behave as you expect? I don't see any problems.

Comment: yes I know that this code is right but when i run this code and input the two integers  ,the output (sum) do not go out in the console ,but when i remove the sign of or (||)the output appeared

Comment: What do you mean by *when i remove the sign of or*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically everything is okay.

The problem is in condition itself. You want to do the loop until the weight is less probably you should reconsider the conditions itself. The first part of condition has now no effect, as `a != b` is always true when `a < b`. Your loop works until `weight_of_Limak == weight_of_Bob` when you put this condition.

Probably you initially wanted to use different comparison sign, probably `<=` instead of `<`?